# Customizing the "Upload Document" Form in SharePoint 2010 based on Content type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

When you click on the name of a library, go to the documents tab, click on "upload document".

An upload form appears that is created using the dialog framework.  The 1st choice on the form is content type.

I need to instead launch a custom infopath form that will allow me to dynamically populate a 2nd dropdown box on the page after the content type (still 1st) dropdown is populated.

I feel like I'm really grasping at straws here.   At this point I could use a reference to a relevant section of a book, a link to a relevant post or even just the correct terms to put into a google search.    What is the correct name for that form?

I found this which seems to teach you how to insert a customized aspx form: http://microsoftsharepointandbeyond.blogspot.com/2009/10/customizing-ootb-sharepoint-forms.html
But I'd really like one that uses Infopath instead.

Any advice or direction you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure doing this with infopath is not possible, the forms are bound to a (codebehind) class in the SharePoint object model, which handles the actual upload (add to list, set field values etc. etc.).

A custom aspx page would be possible though, exactly as the post you mentioned descibes. I agree with the post's author that an HttpModule would be best, because:

- editing the OOTB upload.aspx in the 14 hive would make your environment unsupported (i.e. if anything brakes, MS will have you revert your farm to a supported state before they come and help you.
- The next time you install an update for sharepoint, your changes could be overwritten.